# A function that is both continuous and discontinuous

Tags: continuity, examples-counterexamples, integers

I was asked to find a function that is continuous on Z but discontinuous on R\Z.
as I'm new to continuity I want a feedback on the function I've created, and also tips on what to look for in these types of question!

$f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$} \\
\lfloor x \rfloor & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: That one is continuous for $1≤x<2$, for example.

Comment: A tip for this type of question: to show continuity at a point $x\in\mathbb{R}$, you can apply the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. Do you know it?

Comment: To get started, I suggest looking at the function defined on rationals by $f\left(\frac pq\right)=\frac pq$ and by $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational.  Show that $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$.  Use that to build your example.

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor =x$ when $x \in \mathbb Z$ so you suggestion is continuous if $x=1$ or $x \in \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Z$, but is discontinuous if $x \in \mathbb Z \backslash \{1\}$.  Almost the opposite of what you are asking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the function is discontinuous at every integer other than $1$.

You can take, for instance,$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(\pi x)&\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Q\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Can you check that it works?

Comment: I guess _any_ non-zero value would work in place of $\sin(\pi x)$?

Comment: If I put $1$ instead of $\sin(\pi x)$, then I get a function which is discontinuous *everywhere*.

Comment: Oh I get it, I misunderstood the question -- I was thinking about the restriction $f|_{\mathbb Z}$ being continuous (albeit on a discrete set...).

Comment: Nice! I've used your suggestion, but left f(x) = sin(πx) * D(x), D(x) being the derichlet fucntion, that way it will always be 0 on intergers, but not continuous on not integers!